# How can I query elasticsearch for only one type of record?

Tags: api, search, schema, dsl, elasticsearch

I am issuing a query to elasticsearch and I am getting multiple record types.  How do I limit the results to one type?

Comment: It's a good idea, generally, to include an example of the query you're issuing to ES...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The following query will limit results to records with the type "your_type":

`curl - XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_all/your_type/_search?q=your_query'`

See http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/indices-types.html for more details.

Comment: Link redirects to the home page of Elastic.

Answer (score 16):

You can also use query dsl to filter out results for specific type like this:

```
$ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_search' -d '{
    "query": {
        "filtered" : {
            "filter" : {
                "type" : { "value" : "my_type" }
            }
        }
    }
}
'
```

Update for version 6.1:
Type filter is now replaced by Type Query: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-type-query.html
You can use that in both Query and Filter contexts.

Comment: Deprecated in 2.0.0-beta1.

Use the bool query instead with a must clause for the query and a filter clause for the filter.

Answer (score 3):

```
{
"query" : {
      "filtered" : { 
         "filter" : {
            "bool" : {
            "must" :[{"term":{"_type":"UserAudit"}}, {"term" : {"eventType": "REGISTRATION"}}]
           }
         }
      }
   },
   "aggs":{
      "monthly":{
         "date_histogram":{
            "field":"timestamp",
            "interval":"1y"
         },
         "aggs":{
            "existing_visitor":{
               "terms":{
                  "field":"existingGuest"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

"_type":"UserAudit" condition will look the records only specific to type

Answer (score 2):

On version `2.3` you can query [_type field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/mapping-type-field.html#mapping-type-field) like:

```
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "_type": [ "type_1", "type_2" ] 
    }
  }
}
```

Or if you want to exclude a type:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must_not" : {
        "term" : {
          "_type" : "Hassan"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```